# Django Admin site display differs on apache and django server

Tags: django, django-1.4

I recently installed Django-1.4. While the display of admin page on Django serveris as expected, the display on apache seems to be surprising. Apache is only displaying text on web page why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admin statics are automatically served on devserver only. On production, follow [The doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-the-admin-files). ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX has been deprecated in Django 1.4, use STATIC_ROOT instead.

Comment: thanks.. i have read it and tried creating symlink in my apache root directory.. bt it didnt worked :-(

Comment: then please update your question, what's your config and the output of Apache. As dm03514 suggests, just find out the 404-links and make sure Apache could find corresponding files and serve them correctly

Answer (score 0):

I would try and set up an alias to the media files.  For me this is a little cleaner and more explicit than a symlink.